# Which function is represented in this contour plot?

Tags: analysis, multivariable-calculus, optimization, graphing-functions

This is a kind of unusual question, but I am pretty sure the function in this contour plot has an analytic form. I just don't remember what it was.

[image]

I found it in Stephen Boyd & Lieven Vandenberghes [book](https://web.stanford.edu/%7Eboyd/cvxbook/bv_cvxbook.pdf) (figure 3.2 page 113), but there seems no formula given.

Does anybody know what function this is? I would also help to know the formula for a function similar to this.

Comment: On which page did you found this in the linked book?

Comment: It's on page 113. My guess is that these curves are just an illustration. They were probably draw as closed Bézier splines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The paper [Determining an Aesthetic Inscribed Curve](http://gigl.scs.carleton.ca/node/442) describes how to generate smooth convex curves from convex polygons (Voronoi cells in that paper). It describes both implicit and parametric formulations.
Here is a sample image from that paper:

[image]